# MacBook Pro M2 with macOS repetitive opening of System Settings to "input monitoring" and automatically close

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, settings

A new MacBook Pro M2, with barely anything installed on it, opens the System Settings window by itself sporadocily. Every 2 to 4-ish minutes the System Setting windows opens, navigates to the "Privacy & Security" and then to "Input Monitoring" to finally close. All that within 2 seconds. It takes the focus out of where I am writing which is disruptive.

Here are some details:

- The behavior happens also in Safe Mode
- I unplugged all hubs, mouse, keyboard
- I closed wifi
- Closing all applications and waiting will trigger this behavior
- macOS Sonoma 14.1.1, Apple M2 Max

How can I know which process opens the System Setting? or how can I stop this behavior?

Comment: It sounds like some sort of keylogger is installed, or is trying to install itself. Did you buy this machine new, directly from an authorized dealer? If you acquired it secondhand from an organization, it may be enrolled in multi-device management, in which case you'll either have to get the previous owner to un-enroll it, or else take it to Apple with proof of purchase.